# Put back the value of my settimeout after a cleartimeout

Tags: jquery

I want put back the value of my `setTimeout` to 30 when I click on button `r2` after having clicked on button `r1`, which calls `clearTimeout`.

I tried something, but it puts back the number to 30, then goes back to the number it was before.

Here is the code:

### JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var numb = 30;
    var numba = 100;
    var timer = null;

    function comptage() {
        timer = setTimeout(comptage, 1000);
        $('#test').html(numb);
        $("#progressbar").progressbar({
            value: numba
        });
        numb--;
        numba = numba - (numba / numb);
        if(numb < 0) {
            numb = 0;
            numba = 0;
        }
    };
    comptage();
    $("#r1").click(function () {
        clearTimeout(timer);
    });
    $("#r2").click(function () {
        timer = setTimeout(comptage, 1000);
        var numb = 30;
        var numba = 100;
        $('#test').html(numb);
        $("#progressbar").progressbar({
            value: numba
        });
        numb--;
        numba = numba - (numba / numb);
    });
});
```

### HTML

```
<div id="r1">bouton desactiver</div>
<div id="r2">bouton réactiver</div>
<div id ="affichage_point">
    <div id="bardivs">
        <div id="progressbar"></div>
        <div id="test"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['timer'])){ ?>
    <div id ="r6">
        <?php echo $_SESSION['timer'] ?>
    </div>
    <br/>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the click handler for `r2`, you have:

```
var numb = 30;
var numba = 100;
```

These will create new local variables, and won't touch the global variables.  Remove the `var` here to have it update the global variables.